# HTM5 Input type not working in Ipad

Tags: html

I use

```
<input type="color"/>
```

which works fine in computer but not showing color picker on Ipad ,It only show input field with color code,how can i solve this problem,that it's also work on ipad

Comment: `<input type="color"/>` is not supported in Internet Explorer 11 and earlier versions or **Safari** 9.1 and earlier versions.

Comment: I check on Safari 10.0